# Mac OS X 10.8.5 memory usage on the high side. How to lessen or improve

Tags: macos, mac, memory, macbook, osx-mountain-lion

I bought a Macbook with OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion. It comes with 2GB of memory but it using alot of it from looking at the Activity Monitor.

Here's what it shows: Free: 140 MB Wired: 441.4 MB Active: 706.4 MB Inactive: 757.1 MB Used: 1.86 GB

The kernel_task is using 150 MB and the Avast daemon is using 144.5 MB and Firefox is using 240 MB. Then there's a whole bunch of smaller processes such as mds, Dock, WindowServer, loginwindow, etc along with Activity Monitor and Finder. I'm guessing these add up to the number for 'Active' but I'm trying to figure out what is causing the numbers for 'Wired' and 'Inactive' to be so high and what I can do to lower these, such as stopping some processes or services that are not used.

Thanks.

Comment: Run `purge` from the terminal and then report back the new numbers. Sort by memory usage and kill all non-essential background processes. Although your best option is probably just to install more ram.

Comment: Does purge have any switches or just the one word? Which ones are the non-essential background processes? Will I have to redo this after each reboot?

Comment: Is there any equivalent to Windows 'Services' where I can turn off, disable, or set to manual these processes - such as services for smart cards, telephony, biometric services, etc that are not only non-essential but have no place in my computer.

Comment: Purge has no switches -- it just frees up inactive memory. There is no "windows services" equivalent but there are a few things that can be disabled -- dashboard, notification center, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know, `Wired` memory is memory used by OS X itself to operate, `Active` memory is used by running programs and daemons, and `Inactive` memory is cached data so your most recently/frequently used programs and files can be accessed quickly. I know [Memory Clean](https://fiplab.com/apps/memory-clean-for-mac) is extremely handy tool for freeing up inactive or unnecessary memory, but for the most part OS X does a good job of managing memory. Free memory doesn't actually decide how fast your computer will operate, but instead cached memory speeds things up by allocating space for the programs you use the most, so your hard drive won't be so strained.

If you really feel like you need more memory, you could get rid of `Avast`.